# Change of Variables for double integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm doing the following exercise. However I don't get the book's result:

Consider the transformation $T$ given by the equations:
$$x=u+v,\;\;\;\;\;\;y=v-u^2.$$
A triangle Q in the plane $(u,v)$ has vertices in $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(0,2)$. Consider that  $T(Q)=D$ in the $xy$ plane. Now compute the area of $D$ through a double integral on $Q$.

---

We know that the area function is the constant $1$. Therefore, computing the Jacobian which is $2u$: 
$$a(D)= \int^2_0\int^{2-u}_02u\,dv\,du = \int^2_04u-2u^2 du = \left(2u^2-\frac{2}{3}u^3\right)^2_0=\frac{8}{3}.$$
The correct answer is $\dfrac{14}{3}$. Any thoughts on the problem? Am I missing something concerning the limits of integration?

Comment: I got $1+2u$ for the Jacobian.

Comment: Oh silly me. I wrote a + that looked like x. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In summary, $$\int_0^2 dv \int_0^{2-v}(1+2u) du=\int_0^2 dv (6-5v+v^2) = 14/3.$$